# Why RGBA is making png image blackish?

Tags: opengl, rgba, alpha-transparency

I am trying to capture PNG image with transparent background. I have set GL_RGBA as format in glReadPixels. But the output PNG image looks a little blackish or with saturated color. If backgrouund is not transparent that is if I use GL_RGB format in glReadPixels expected image is captured.
Note: In both cases, I am capturing translucent(partially transparent) shaded cube. If cube is completely opaque, RGBA format works fine.
Any ideas as to why this is happening for transparent background?

Blackish image with RGBA format:

[image: Blackish image with RGBA format]

Image with RGB format:

[image: Image with RGB format]

Comment: Can you post your code / shaders?

Answer (score -1):

The cube looks darker because it's semitransparent, and whatever you use to view the image blends the semitransparent parts of it with black background.

You might argue that the cube in the picture shouldn't be semitransparent since it's drawn on top of a completely opaque background, but the problem is that the widely-used

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

blending mode (which you seem to use as well) is known to produce incorrect alpha values when used to draw semitransparent objects.

Usually you can't see it because alpha is discarded when drawing to the default framebuffer, but it becomes prominent when inspecting outputs of `glReadPixels`.

---

As you noticed, to solve it you can simply discard the alpha component.

But if you for some reason need to have a *proper* blending without those problems, you need

```
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Note that for this funciton to work, both source and destination images have to be in *premultiplied alpha* format. That is, you need to do `color.rgb *= color.a` 
 as a last step in your shaders.

The inverse operation (`color.rgb /= color.a`) can be used to convert an image back to the regular format, but if your images are completely opaque, this step is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @HolyBlackCat. If I understand you right, you are saying that the pixels returned by glReadpixels have incorrect alpha value. Is it possible to correct it after reading the pixels? I may not be at liberty to change the shader? Or is it possible to change the blend function just before reading the pixels?

Comment: @Ashwini *"Is it possible to correct it after reading the pixels?"* Yes, it shouldn't be hard at all. *"is it possible to change the blend function just before reading the pixels"* Blend function doesn't affect `glReadPixels` itself. You'd need to change blend function before drawing the frame. If you can't change the shader to use premultiplied alpha, I suggest changing blend function to `glBlendFuncSeparate(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ZERO, GL_ONE);`, to lock image alpha to `1`.